# Upsells won't show custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

F.y.i. The website I'm making is for buying trips on a sailboat.

My upsells file shows the upsell items that are added in the admin (like the upsells file would normally do). The product variable is 'created' like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($this->getItemCollection()->getItems() as $_link):
// where $_link contains all the product options
endforeach
?>
```

Later, I have an attribute called 'period' (a select) which shows the period when the ship sets sail.

```
<?php echo $_link->getAttribute('period'); ?>
```

Problem, it returns 'null', why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<?php echo $_link->getAttribute('period'); ?>
```

If the attribute is of type `select` then use :

```
<?php echo $_link->getAttributeText('period'); ?>
```

If the attribute is of type `text` than use:

```
<?php echo $_link->getData('period'); ?>

OR

<?php echo $_link->getPeriod(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks alot! The first one returned the select text (forgot to mention that).